# Keras low support for 1 even though its %61 of data

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

Here is the data frame that contains first 3 datas from each column:

```
stack_overflow_df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[64,21,55],
                                 'b':[1,0,1],
                                 'c':[66,94,64],
                                 'd':[160,98,160],
                                 'e':[83,47,77],
                                 'f':[160,296,270],
                                 'g':[1.80,6.75,1.99],
                                 'h':[0.012,1.060,0.003],
                                  'y_col':[0,1,0]})
```

y_col was negative,positive,negative etc. I encoded it.
This is how I encoded the y_col:

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['class'],drop_first=True)],axis=1).drop('class',axis=1)
```

Here is the data preprocessing and creating of x_train,y_train etc.:

```
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df.drop('positive',axis=1))
y = df['positive']
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=101)
```

This is the model:

```
model = Sequential(name='Simple_Model_HDP')

model.add(Dense(8,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Fitting process:

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train,
         epochs=350,
         validation_data=[X_test,y_test],
         batch_size=8,
         callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='loss',mode='min',patience=15)])
```

And the prediction part is:

```
print(classification_report(model.predict(X_test).astype('int32'),y_test))
```

The accuracy is 0.54, but there seems to be a problem: the support for `1` is super low. There are 294 support for `0` while there are only 36 support for `1`.

```
y_train.mean() = 0.625
y_test.mean() = 0.578
```

What is the problem here? I feel like I miss something small, but I couldn't find a thing for nearly an hour.I found an answer on stackoverflow that says he/she used different columns for x_test and x_train, but it is not the case in my code for sure.